# The use of kwarg wrap for a pyplot.text artist in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I run this script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
plt.axis([0, 10, 0, 10])
t = "This is a really long string that I'd rather have wrapped so that it"\
    " doesn't go outside of the figure, but if it's long enough it will go"\
    " off the top or bottom!"
plt.text(-1, 0, t, ha='left', rotation=-15, wrap=True)
plt.show()
```

then I receive this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eric/Desktop/tsd.py", line 10, in <module>
plt.text(4, 1, t, ha='left', rotation=15, wrap=True)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3397, in text
    ret = gca().text(x, y, s, fontdict=fontdict, withdash=withdash, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 3380, in text
    t.update(kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 739, in update
    raise AttributeError('Unknown property %s' % k)
AttributeError: Unknown property wrap
```

The script I executed was copied directly from the matplotlib.org webpage http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/examples/text_labels_and_annotations/autowrap_demo.html. How can I fix or configure my system to enable the functionality of wrap?

I am using matplotlib 1.5, python 2.7 and ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks!

Comment: You are not using 1.5 if the keyword is not working, what does  `matplotlib.__version__` output? I would `pip2 install -u matplotlib` and I guarantee it will work

Comment: I can reproduce this error message with 1.4.3. There is no error message with 1.5.0 but also no wrapping.

Comment: I now realize I have version 1.3. Thank you for making me aware. Now my goal is install matplotlib 1.5. Perhaps I must create a new question for that. I tried [ pip2 install -u matplotlib ] at linux terminal but it return error:
Usage:   
  pip install [options] <requirement specifier> ...

  pip install [options] -r <requirements file> ...

  pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...

  pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...

  pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...


no such option: -u

Do you know other way to obtain current stable release of matplotlib on ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this error message with 1.4.3. There is no error message with 1.5.0. You need to install matplotlib 1.5.

The easiest way is to to use [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) or [Miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html).
Then it comes as easy as:

```
conda install matplotlib
```

This works well for Linux, Mac and Windows.

Comment: I obtained the source code of matplotlib 1.5 from github and I installed via [sudo python setup.py install] at linux terminal. And you are correct: with matplotlib 1.5 there is functionality of text wrap.